# Usar case en el select con registros que contienen null en sql server

Tags: base-de-datos

Deseo una columna estatus creada por mi y esta columna sale tomando en cuenta que tenga 3 fechas diferentes en una sola tabla es decir `fecha1, fecha2 y fecha3`.
Como nota el sql server no soporta el `if`.
Las restricciones son:

- Si `fecha1` es diferente de `null` y `fecha2` y `fecha3` son `null` estatus es escriturado.
- Si `fecha2` es diferente de `null` y `fecha1` y `fecha3` son `null` el estatus es en proceso.
- Si `fecha3` es diferente de `null` y `fecha1` y `fecha2` son `null` el estatus es cancelado.
- Si todas las fechas son `null` el estatus es terminado.

Intenté hacer un `case` en el `select` pero me marcar error cuando comparo las fechas con `is null` o `is not null`.
Después use la función `isnull()` y si corre pero solo para uno o dos restricciones y las demás no las hace o marcar warnings

Comment: ¿qué error te marca al comparar con `is null` o `is not null`?

Comment: Hola, qué SQL Server es? Te soporta un trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que nuestros datos son:

```
create table datos (
  fecha1 datetime,
  fecha2 datetime,
  fecha3 datetime
)

insert into datos values ('05-20-2019',null,null);
insert into datos values (null,'05-20-2019',null);
insert into datos values (null,null,'05-20-2019');
insert into datos values (null,null,null);
```

Podemos hacer el siguiente case:

```
select 
  case when fecha1 is not null and fecha2 is null and fecha3 is null then 'escriturado' 
       when fecha1 is null and fecha2 is not null and fecha3 is null then 'proceso'
       when fecha1 is null and fecha2 is null and fecha3 is not null then 'cancelado'
       else 'terminado'
  end status from datos;
```

Puede ser que hayas tenido problemas con la sentencia, tenemos que debe comenzar con la palabras "CASE" y terminar con la palabra "END", dentro de esas dos palabras van las condiciones "WHEN" cuando se presente una condición "THEN" entonces hacer algo y puede haber un "ELSE" sino se dan esas condiciones.

Puedes probar acá el query:
[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9d370/6)